# How to share a CPU quota among multiple containers?

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, cgroups

Assume I have a pod with 3 containers: ***`X`***, ***`Y`***, and ***`Z`***.

**K8S** can set a cpu limit for each container in a pod. However, if I set `1000M` CPU limit to each container, then any container cannot use more than `1000M` CPU even if the other two are ilde, which is not what I want.

I want to set a CPU quota of `3000M` to the pod, rather than to each container. For example, if ***`X`*** & ***`Y`*** are idle, ***`Z`*** can use `3000M` CPU; if ***`X`*** is using `1500M` CPU, ***`Y`*** is using `1000M` CPU, then ***`Z`*** can only use `500M` CPU.

So, my question is:

**How to share a CPU quota among multiple containers?**

Answer (score 2):

> I must set limits because I must pay for my usage to the cloud provider.

In such a case, I would recommend you to use [Vertical-Pod-AutoScaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler#limits-control) along with a [Limit Range](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/).

A `LimitRange` provides constraints that can:

- Enforce minimum and maximum compute resources usage per Pod or Container in a namespace.

And the VPA will try to cap recommendations between min and max of `limitRanges` based on the current usages.

**N.B.:** Make sure you have [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) installed in your cluster to enable the VPA.

Comment: This can help shift the limits over time but it won't help with short term bursting. VPA is looking at rolling averages over days, not seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't set a CPU limit at all. Or set it to some higher value. Setting a CPU limit should only happen in situations where it's known to be needed, in general they do more harm than good.

Comment: I must set limits because I must pay for my usage to the cloud provider.

Comment: One of the EKS+Fargate or GKE Autopilot setups? That's hard, there really isn't an answer there.